# NoSuchMethodError while iterating Vertices in OrientDB

Tags: java, orientdb, graph-databases

Folks,

New to OrientBD, just trying to iterate through vertices but getting the following error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocumentInternal.getImmutableSchemaClass(Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/record/impl/ODocument;)Lcom/orientechnologies/orient/core/metadata/schema/OClass;
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterator.next(OrientElementIterator.java:69)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterator.next(OrientElementIterator.java:34)
    at Orient.OrientConnectionMain.main(OrientConnectionMain.java:74)

Code:

```
package Orient;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphFactory;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientVertexType;

import java.util.Iterator;

import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;


public class OrientConnectionMain 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        OrientGraph graph = new OrientGraph("remote:URL/DBName", "*", "*");
        System.out.println(graph.countVertices());

         for (Vertex v : graph.getVertices()) {
                System.out.println(v.getProperty("product_name"));
            }

            //       for (Vertex v : (Iterable<Vertex>) graph.command(
            //                  new OCommandSQL("SELECT EXPAND( IN('belongs_to_category') ) FROM Category WHERE category_id='4590'")).execute()) 
                                {
            //                        System.out.println("- Product: " + v);
            //                  }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of the OrientDB and Tinkerpop libraries are you using?

Comment: orientdb-core 2.2.15,orientdb-client 2.2.15,blueprints-core 2.6.0